# The marginals of the nested logit are identical?

Tags: probability, distributions, econometrics, logit, multinomial-logit

Consider three random variables $\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ and suppose that their joint CDF
is

$$
F(\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)\equiv \exp\Bigg[-\exp(-\epsilon_0)- \bigg[\exp\Big(-\frac{\epsilon_1}{\sigma}\Big)+\exp\Big(-\frac{\epsilon_2}{\sigma}\Big)\bigg]^\sigma\Bigg]
$$

with $\sigma\in (0,1)$.

This is an example of [nested logit model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice#G._Nested_Logit_and_Generalized_Extreme_Value_(GEV)_models).

My understanding on the nested logit model is that, according to the specification above,

**1)** $\epsilon_0\perp \epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_0\perp \epsilon_2$

**2)** $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ are correlated (when $\sigma=1$, then $\{\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\}$ are i.i.d. Gumbel with location $0$ and scale $1$).

**3)** $\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ are distributed as Gumbel.

**Question:** is it true that $\epsilon_0\sim \epsilon_1\sim \epsilon_2$? Why?